Dealing with Jitter: Overcoming Character Movement Issues in Unity with Rigidbody
I'm encountering an issue where my character in Unity experiences unexpected jitter in the Y-axis while moving. This jitter is unwanted and disrupts the smoothness of the character's movement. I'm utilizing a Rigidbody component for character movement. How can I resolve this Y-axis jitter and ensure consistent and smooth character movement
my code :
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 6f; // The speed at which the player moves

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private float horizontalInput;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Calculate the movement force
        Vector3 movementForce = new Vector3(horizontalInput * moveSpeed * 2f, 0f, 0f);

        // Apply the movement force to the player's Rigidbody
        rb.AddForce(movementForce, ForceMode.Force);
    }
}

my rigidbody settings :
Mass : 1
Drag : 0
Angular Drag : 0.05
Garvity : Checked
Is Kinematic : Unchecked
interpolate : interpolate
Colision Detection : Continuous
Freeze Position : All Unchecked
Freeze Rootation : All Checked

Despite trying various approaches like collider adjustments and performance optimizations, the jitter persists

The problem was the ground. This problem occurs when several planes are placed next to each other, but when we have a large plane, everything is fine. How to solve this problem? My ground is made up of several planes and I don't want to use a large plane

How does your camera follow the player?

I believe that the issue is due to the fact that you have the horizontalInput in your Update() function. Here is why :
As you know Update() is called once every frame, so the frequency at which it's called depends on the frame rate. If the frame rate fluctuates, it can lead to variations in the input values retrieved in each frame.
To fix this just put horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); in the FixedUpdate().
PS : Always use FixedUpdate() for Physics. This ensures that physics calculations are synchronized with the physics engine's update rate and therefore, reduce jitter.
Hope this helps, good luck

The code is causing occasional small changes in the character's position along the y-axis. These changes have values of either 0.002 or 0.014, which is not desirable. Which part of the code is responsible for these changes?

@indiedeveloper Do these fluctuations happen with the updated version of the code ?

the updated version has the same problem as before

Try Checking "Freeze Position : Y Axis" in rigidbody.

While "Freeze Position" is a good idea, but it raises the question of how the player can still perform jumps.  Overall, I believe that this simple code should not cause such fluctuations

use if statements to limit the constraints.

The problem was the ground. This problem occurs when several planes are placed next to each other, but when we have a large plane, everything is fine.
How to solve this problem? My ground is made up of several planes and I don't want to use a large plane

I dont want to be rude with Emlf9, but checking the input in the FixedUpdate loop is dangerous, since the method is not thought to gather player input, you will miss a lot of inputs, and the game won't feel responsive at all.
You can either:

Make the rigidbody interpolation to Interpolate
Rewrite your code as it follows:

    //Note: you did forget to multiply the movementForce by Time.[delta/fixedDelta]Time
    //If you dont multiply by Time.deltaTime players with high end pcs will move faster!
    private void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        // Calculate the movement force
        Vector3 movementForce = new Vector3(horizontalInput * moveSpeed * 2f, 0f, 0f);

        // Apply the movement force to the player's Rigidbody
        rb.AddForce(movementForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Force);
    }

Regarding the little jumps the ball is making, you can try adding a downforce to the ball:
    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 movementForce = new Vector3(horizontalInput * moveSpeed * 2f, 0f, 0f);
        //I was thinking about -transform.up but if the ball rolls it's not going to be good
        Vector3 downForce = -Vector3.up * downForceStrength;
        rb.AddForce((movementForce + downForce) * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Force);
    }

Ps: you don't need to worry about performance until you have a new GTA 6 running, first make the game work, then optimize it before the release.

The code is causing occasional small changes in the character's position along the y-axis. These changes have values of either 0.002 or 0.014, which is not desirable. Which part of the code is responsible for these changes?

Probably the ball bounces a bit on the ground, why is that "not desirable"? The performance won't be affected by this unless the rigidbody, while standing still, does never go in the sleep mode.

Not rude. I understand what you mean but FixedUpdate() helps synchronization with physics, optimization stability and reduces jitter. And using Interpolate is horrible for performance. Finally I have to say that I disagree with your last statement. You do not optimize a game before release but during the whole process. Addressing performance issues early can prevent them from becoming more challenging to solve as the project grows in complexity. Even small games can suffer from performance issues, but players expect smooth gameplay regardless. Ignoring optimization will just be delaying.

It's true, but as an indie developer, if you keep optimizing your game before the release, probably you will never release it, because you are over complicating the project and you don't have enought time in order to make everything perfect!

I completely understand what you mean, but us as indies are competing against tripleA, doubleA and indie studios and many other indie devs who do optimise. Players just don t care who make the game as long as it is good.

True, but today we are seeing examples of Indie teams succeding thanks to the gameplay, rather than graphics and other secondary things, just look at battlebit remastered.
I was a bit surprised when you said interpolation hits performance, it just interpolates so why should it hit the CPU? Have you got any website speaking about this or it's just your thought?

@PatrickMoling The fluctuations can be frustrating for players who want to move smoothly.
Sometimes it seems like the player is jumping

Drag a physics material to the terrain, set the bounce to 0 and friction to 1.
You can also try to add a constant force to the ball, so it's bound to be grounded:
movementForce -= transform.up * stayingGroundedForce;

Graphics are highly unimportant for us, I 100% agree with you but even using Post-Processing on low-poly graphics cause frame rate drops. And while for the interpolate hits performance its not just me, just google "interpolate performance issues" and you will have a long list

True, being an indie dev is very challenging, everyone is expecting you to make the best out of the little time you have, I don't know why I love it I must really like hurting myself. As for the performance hit for interpolation I am just seeing that they say "faster interpolation" regarding the speed of interpolation literally, not the hardware speed while executing it, the performance shouldn't be damaged at all since it is an extremely simple operation, I will conduct some tests though, I don't like speaking without proofs.

Add this stage yes.The performance will not be affected this much, but when the game is fully fleshed out you bet that performance will be affected.

@PatrickMoling The problem was the ground. This problem occurs when several planes are placed next to each other, but when we have a large plane, everything is fine.
How to solve this problem? My ground is made up of several planes and I don't want to use a large plane

you can make the plane follow the player, snap the x and z postion of it to the player position.
